# Moving elements to end of previous line

Tags: excel, batch-file, notepad++

I have a problem with moving a defined text block ("PT") **to the end of its previous line**.. for eg, consider the following :-

> 100001,-6.0704
>  PT
>   100061,19.1127
>  100122,8.1831
>   PT

I need that to be :-

> 100001,-6.0704PT
>   100061,19.1127
>  100122,8.1831PT

I have a large irregularly repeating data like this.. and need to achieve this..(moving the "PT" to currentline-1")

I have Notepad++  I need to achieve this somehow.. maybe using spreadsheets? online tools? and how? macros? batch files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this as a first attempt

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set prevline=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (a.txt) do (
  if '%%a'=='PT' (
   echo !prevline!PT
   set prevline=
  ) else (
   if not '!prevline!'=='' echo !prevline! 
   set prevline=%%a
 ) 
)
```

this batch file iterates over all the lines of the a.txt file, storing each line in the variable `prevline`, if it happens to find the 'PT' string it spits the stored line and concatenates the PT, if it happens not to find the PT string, it spits just the stored line and stores the new line.

For a further explanation, see `help for` and `help set`.

Comment: Thanks! this works like a charm.. Btw is this line : if not '!prevline!'==''    used to ignore blank spaces?

Comment: yes it does. It also works with the `set prevline=` when PT is found to prevent duplicates; but this might not be your desired behavior.